# Print email attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

I came across this code, which prints email.

I am trying to print attachments.

This as well should be limited to email sent by senttoprint@test.com for example OR if they have specific subject like WEB ORDER #2345.

```
Sub PrintEmail()
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
    Dim strTempFolder As String
    Dim strMailDocument As String
    Dim objMailDocument As Word.Document
    Dim strPrinter As String

    Select Case Application.ActiveWindow.Class
        Case olInspector
            Set objItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        Case olExplorer
            Set objItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    End Select
 
    If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
        Set objMail = objItem
 
        Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        strTempFolder = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE")) & "\AppData\Local\Temp"
        strMailDocument = strTempFolder & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddssnn") & ".doc"
        objMail.SaveAs strMailDocument, olDoc
 
        Set objMailDocument = objWordApp.Documents.Open(strMailDocument)
        objWordApp.Visible = True
        objMailDocument.Activate
 
        strPrinter = objWordApp.ActivePrinter
        'Change to the name of specific printer
        objWordApp.ActivePrinter = "Specific Printer"
        objWordApp.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:=wdPrintDocumentContent
        objWordApp.ActivePrinter = strPrinter
 
        objMailDocument.Close False
        objWordApp.Quit
        Kill strMailDocument
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to find items from a folder that corresponds to your conditions and should be printed. Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. The `Restrict` method is an alternative to using the `Find` method or `FindNext` method to iterate over specific items within a collection. The `Find` or `FindNext` methods are faster than filtering if there are a small number of items. The `Restrict` method is significantly faster if there is a large number of items in the collection, especially if only a few items in a large collection are expected to be found.

But if you need to find items from multiple folders I'd recommend using the `AdvancedSearch` method instead:

```
Public m_SearchComplete As Boolean  

Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)  
    If SearchObject.Tag = "MySearch" Then  
        m_SearchComplete = True  
    End If  
End Sub  

Sub TestSearchForMultipleFolders()  
    Dim Scope As String  
    Dim Filter As String  
    Dim MySearch As Outlook.Search  
    Dim MyTable As Outlook.Table  
    Dim nextRow As Outlook.Row  
    m_SearchComplete = False  
    'Establish scope for multiple folders  
    Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _  
    olFolderInbox).FolderPath _  
    & "','" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _  
    olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"  
    'Establish filter  
    If Application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled Then  
        Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _  
        & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'Office'"  
    Else  
        Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _  
        & Chr(34) & " like '%Office%'"  
    End If  
    Set MySearch = Application.AdvancedSearch( _  
    Scope, Filter, True, "MySearch")  
    While m_SearchComplete <> True  
        DoEvents  
    Wend  
    Set MyTable = MySearch.GetTable  
    Do Until MyTable.EndOfTable  
        Set nextRow = MyTable.GetNextRow()  
        Debug.Print nextRow("Subject")  
    Loop  
End Sub
```